# Getting updated coordinates after dragging in Leaflet

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, geojson, react-leaflet

I am using react-leaflet and [Leaflet.Path.Drag](https://github.com/w8r/Leaflet.Path.Drag) to drag GeoJSON. I would need to keep GeoJSON coordinations in React state. The issue is that updated coordinations on `dragEnd` are not corrent and GeoJSON position is not correct after dragging.

[codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-villani-jbc7l?file=/src/App.js)

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { MapContainer, GeoJSON, TileLayer, useMap } from "react-leaflet";
import "./styles.css";
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";

require("leaflet-path-drag");

export default function App() {
  const geoJSONRef = React.useRef(null);
  const [coordinates, setCoordinates] = React.useState([
    [-104.98569488525392, 39.63431579014969],
    [-104.98569488525392, 39.64165260123419],
    [-104.97161865234376, 39.64165260123419],
    [-104.97161865234376, 39.63431579014969]
  ]);

  const handleFeature = (layer) => {
    layer.makeDraggable();
    layer.dragging.enable();

    layer.on("dragend", function (e) {
      const latLngs = e.target.getLatLngs()[0];
      console.log({ latLngs });
      const coordinates = latLngs.map((point) => [point.lng, point.lat]);
      geoJSONRef.current.eachLayer((geoLayer) => {
        console.log(geoLayer.getLatLngs()[0]);
      });
      setCoordinates(coordinates);
    });
  };

  const object = {
    polygon: {
      type: "FeatureCollection",
      features: [
        {
          type: "Feature",
          properties: {},
          geometry: {
            type: "Polygon",
            coordinates: [[...coordinates]]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  };

  return (
    <MapContainer center={[39.63563779557324, -104.99234676361085]} zoom={12}>
      <TileLayer
        attribution='&amp;copy <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        url="https://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
      />
      <GeoJSON
        key={`${coordinates}`}
        ref={geoJSONRef}
        data={object.polygon}
        style={() => ({
          color: "green",
          weight: 3,
          opacity: 0.5
        })}
        draggable={true}
        pmIgnore={false}
        onEachFeature={(feature, layer) => handleFeature(layer)}
      ></GeoJSON>
    </MapContainer>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why but `e.target._latlngs[0]` and `e.target.getLatLngs()[0];` give a different result. Therefore if you try using the first expression it works as expected without moving further the dragged polygon

```
layer.on("dragend", function (e) {
      const latLngs = e.target._latlngs[0]; // here replace the expression
      const coordinates = latLngs.map((point) => [point.lng, point.lat]);
      geoJSONRef.current.eachLayer((geoLayer) => {
        // console.log(geoLayer.getLatLngs()[0]);
      });
      setCoordinates(coordinates);
});
```

Comment: This was helpful @kboul. I'm working with a similar problem. But did you encounter the problem that trying to `setCoordinates(...)` or any other state using a React useState hook triggers errors? I get errors internal to Leaflet or Leaflet.Path.Drag similar to `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'mouseEventToContainerPoint')` whenever I try to do this.